# Necesito ayuda con un proyecto en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms, excel, datagrid

Buenas, estoy realizando un proyecto en windows form y lo que hace es subir un archivo excel pasar los datos a un dataGridView y guardarlos en una base de datos MySQL, el problema es que este excel muestra datos de un ciclo de 4 meses y este es el ultimo mes por ende muestra FEBRERO, MARZO, ABRIL Y MAYO el próximo mes mostrará JUNIO, JULIO, AGOSTO Y SEPTIEMBRE no se como hacer el cambio del nombre de los meses según corresponda a cada periodo, pensé en crear la base de datos con los 12 meses e ir llenando según el header del dataGridView pero no se como puedo guardarlo en una variable o algo.

Dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar.

ESTA ES LA CLASE IMPORTAEXCEL

```
class importarExcel
{
    OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter;
    DataTable dt;

    public void importarExcel(DataGridView dgv, String nombreHoja, string ruta)
    {
        try
        {

            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'");
            MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + nombreHoja + "$]", conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La ruta y/o el Nombre de la hoja son incorrectos");
        }
    }
```

ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO DEL BOTÓN PARA BUSCAR EL ARCHIVO

```
        string ruta = "";

        OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile1.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx";
        openfile1.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
        if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (openfile1.FileName.Equals("") == false)
            {
                ruta = openfile1.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = ruta;
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox2.Focus();
                textBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

ESTE EL CÓDIGO DEL BOTÓN PARA IMPORTAR LOS DATOS AL DATAGRIDVIEW

```
string nom = textBox2.Text;
string ruta = textBox1.Text;
new importar().importarExcel(dataGridView1, nom, ruta);
```

Y ESTE EL CÓDIGO DEL BOTÓN PARA SUBIRLO A LA BD

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)//CICLO PARA RECORRER LA TABLA
        {
            a1 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Sold-to party"].Value);
            a2 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Ship-to-party"].Value);
            a3 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Cliente"].Value);
            a4 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Cotización"].Value);
            a5 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Material"].Value);
            a6 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Descripción"].Value);
            a7 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Febrero"].Value);
            a8 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Marzo"].Value);
            a9 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Abril"].Value);
            a10 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Mayo"].Value);
            a11 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Total Cotizado"].Value);
            a12 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["PO Number"].Value);
            a13 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Cantidad Cotización"].Value);
            a14 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Cantidad OC"].Value);
            a15 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Valor OC"].Value);
            a16 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Éxito"].Value);
            a17 = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["SBU"].Value);

            string estado="";//VARIBLE HAY QUE PROGRAMAR EL ESTADO

            con.ingresarcotizaciones(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, int.Parse(a7), int.Parse(a8), int.Parse(a9), int.Parse(a10), int.Parse(a11), a12, int.Parse(a13), int.Parse(a14), int.Parse(a15), int.Parse(a16), int.Parse(a17), estado);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que estas diseñando de forma incorreca la persistencia, los meses no deberias definirlos como columnas, sino como filas en una tabla relacionada

Entonces tendras la tabla de cotizaciones y despues por cada mes el valor en una tabla relacionada, habria que determinar cual seria la key de esa tabla, alguna forma de identificar la cabecera de los datos.

```
Cotizaciones  (tabla)
CotizacionId  PK
Cliente
Material
Descripción
//resto columnas

CotizacionMeses (tabla)
CotizacionMesesId  PK
CotizacionId  
Mes  (este campo tomara los valores del 1 al 12)
Monto
```

Entonces insertas los datos comunes en "Cotizaciones" y despues por cada mes que vas teniendo datos insertas en "CotizacionMeses", de esta forma al principio insertaras los primeros 4 meses y despues cuando tengas los demas iras completando con nuevos inserts